# AX 2012 AIF Service don't retrieve table on XML

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, aif

for a project I need to change the AIF service  called "SalesSalesEInvoice". In particular, I need to retrieve the CustPaymModeTable on the result XML.
In the query used by the service, this table is present and is joined with CustTrans (relationship based on PaymMode field). 
We debugged the service execution and we've observed that the table is not retrieved because it is not linked via surrogate key (AifSecurityInference.inferField()).
Did you ever had (and solved) that problem?
How can we force the recovery of the table when the join is not based on recid?

Comment: The relation is not an issue at all. Please check if data exists in CustPaymModeTable for related CustTrans and this table enabled in data policy

Comment: data exist. I have turn on all field in System administration > Setup > Services and Application Integration Framework > Outbound ports>Data policies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a range set in CustPaymModeTable. So please verify if there is record exists with that range value.

[image]